# Fear of hurting or betraying others

Tags: meaning

Adopted children often have a fear of hurting or betraying their adoptive parents. I think this is different than the fear of abandonment, which is also found in adopted children. Is there a better name for the fear of hurting or betraying? I'm having difficulty finding literature about this online.

E.g.: Fred, an adopted child, has an intense fear of __________________, which manifests whenever he thinks he has hurt or betrayed his adoptive parents.

Comment: This site requires: "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see the help section: About single word requests".  Please edit your question to include a sentence with a blank for the word or phrase you are looking for.  Otherwise, your question may be closed.

Comment: This question seems to me more to do with society and family relationships than the English Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disloyal***

> Adopted children often fear being **disloyal** to their adoptive parents
>   if they try to learn who their birth parents are, even if only for
>   medical purposes.

Disloyal, [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disloyal)

> not loyal or faithful; deserting one's allegiance or duty

Because disloyal is not loyal, let's define loyal: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loyal):

> having or showing complete and constant support for someone or
>   something

Addition:  The blank in the OP's edited post would be disloyalty, which is the act of being disloyal.

Comment: This is really good. Might be the word/phrase I'm looking for. Yet I am still open to more suggestions, as there might be other interesting answers.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for ***alienation***

> a withdrawing or separation of a person or a person's affections from an object or position of former attachment
>   *from [M-W.com/alienation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alienation)*

or ***estrangement***:

> to arouse especially mutual enmity or indifference in where there had formerly been love, affection, or friendliness
>   *from [M-W.com/estrange](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/estrange)*

These options clearly focus on the consequence of the hurt or betrayal, rather than the hurt or betrayal itself, but they may be appropriate.